# Anylogic - How to measure work in process inventory (WIP) within simulation

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I am currently working on a simple simulation that consists of 4 manufacturing workstations with different processing times and I would like to measure the WIP inside the system. The model is PennyFab2 in case anybody knows it.

So far, I have measured throughput and cycle time and I am calculating WIP using Little's law, however the results don't match he expectations. The cycle time is measured by using the time measure start and time measure end agents and the throughput by simply counting how many pieces flow through the end of the simulation.

Any ideas on how to directly measure WIP without using Little's law?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For little's law you count the arrivals, not the exits... but maybe it doesn't make a difference...

Otherwise.. There are so many ways

- you can count the number of agents inside your system using a RestrictedAreaStart block and use the entitiesInside() function
- You can just have a variable that adds +1 if something enters and -1 if something exits

No matter what, you need to add the information into a dataset or a statistics object and you get the mean of agents in your system

Answer (score 0):

Little's Law defines the relationship between:

- Work in Process =(WIP)
- Throughput (or Flow rate)
- Lead Time (or Flow Time)

[image]

This means that if you have 2 of the three you can calculate the third.

Since you have a simulation model you can record all three items explicitly and this would be my advice.
Little's Law should then be used to validate if you are recording the 3 values correctly.

You can record them as follows.

WIP = Record the average number of items in your system

- Simplest way would be to count the number of items that entered the system and subtract the number of items that left the system. You simply do this calculation every time unit that makes sense for the resolution of your model (hourly, daily, weekly etc) and save the values to a DataSet or Statistics Object

Lead Time = The time a unit takes from entering the system to leaving the system

- If you are using the Process Modelling Library (PML) simply use the [timeMeasureStart](https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/timemeasurestart.html#timemeasureend) and [timeMeasureEnd](https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/timemeasurestart.html#timemeasureend) Blocks, see the example model in the help file.

Throughput = the number of units out of the system per time unit

- If you run the model and your average WIP is 10 units and on average a unit takes 5 days to exit the system, your throughput will be `10 units/5 days = 2 units/day`
- You can validate this by taking the total units that exited your system at the end of the simulation and dividing it by the number of time units your model ran
- if you run a model with the above characteristics for 10 days you would expect 20 units to have exited the system.